# Defining a union of objects that have the same property but different value type

Tags: typescript

What's the idiomatic way to define an `Item` that can be either:

```
{
  title: string;
  content: string[]
}
```

or

```
{
  content: string;
}
```

but not:

```
{
  title: string;
  content: string
}
```

This doesn't seem to work:

```
type Item = {
  title: string;
  content: string[]
} | {
  content: string;
}

const item: Item = { // TypeScript doesn't complain, and I want it to
  title: "Title",
  content: "Content"
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG8CwAoKVgEtgAbCALigGdgAnfAOwHMBubXAYwHs75vyrbGAbQC62AL5QAPulZRO3CL0o16zcdmzyqUQonJxEKGTjyES5AEQAVMxAsAaWfJ7BLAYS4uL6rBt9YgA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `title?: undefined` to the second union element.

```
type Item = {
  title: string;
  content: string[]
} | {
  content: string;
  title?: undefined
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG8CwAoKVgEtgAbCALigGdgAnfAOwHMBubXAYwHs75vyrbGAbQC62AL5QAPulZRO3CL0o16zWQWIQA-OQCudACYQAZvQgHx2bPKpRCicnEQoZOPIRLkARABUPELwAaWXkeYG8AYS4wr0ssK3isIA)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where this union behavior is documented? I'd like to understand WHY TypeScript is behaving this way.

Comment: @MishaMoroshko - It all boils down to the structural type system of TypeScript. Excess property checks are not done in most places. So having extra properties is completely fine, as long as the type constraint is fulfilled. By adding `title?: undefined` to the type, we tighten the constraint. The `item` object from above now breaks this constraint because `content` is a `string` but `title` is not `undefined`. This causes the error.